# Azure SQL Server provisioning blocked

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-resource-manager

I'm using Powershell with resource templates to provision SQL Servers (and databases) in Azure.  After a few provisions it starts returning this error:

New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 2:40:18 PM - Resource Microsoft.Sql/servers 'oao-sql01-gd6helghx' failed with message 'Subscription 'mysubscription Guid here'
is not ready for the operation because another operation is currently in progress. Please wait a few minutes and then try the operation again.'

There is no operation currently in progress that I can ascertain. Any Sql Servers I have provisioned are operational and I am able to provision other kinds of resources with no problems.

If I wait several hours (not a few minutes), it will let me provision a new server but soon after blocks me again.  Is there some kind of throttling going on if I am doing a bunch of provisioning/teardown?

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: I also faced similar issues couple of months back. As a good rule use [this]{https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt603603.aspx} command to actually verify the operations executing on the Azure resource group. I am sure it will give you some good insights.

Comment: Are you able to share the ARM template you used to deploy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that after Azure support bumped my quota of SQL Server, this began to work a while later.  Not sure why it took so long to kick in as I only had 1 server at the time.  The best explanation was that the counter tracking the number of DB's against our quota got stale and didn't clear for a while.  The default quota is 6 SQL Server instances.